# Google Analytics: status not installed and no views in real time

Tags: google-analytics

I just (literally) finished installing google analytics to my website on just one page. On the Google Analytics page I've already checked if the code is correct and is universal.

My code tracking status is "not installed" and I can't see active users when i'm using a realtime report (i've deleted the exclusion of my own domain). Seeing I have a lot of js, i thought there might be a conflict, so I used the google analytics debugger and this is what it gives
Hoping anyone could help me out... 
Thank you

(I cant post pictures because I don't have enough reputation points unfortunately)

output of debugger:
Initializing Google Analytics.

```html
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("create", "UA-49537527-2", "auto")
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 Creating new tracker: t0
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 Auto cookieDomain found: "benelux-pet.com"
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("send", "pageview")
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 Setting throttling cookie: "_gat"
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 
Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j31d&a=951092047&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.benelux-pet.com%2FBE%2FNL%2Findex.html&ul=nl&de=UTF-8&dt=Benelux&sd=24-…~&jid=43634674&cid=96833174.1417007305&tid=UA-49537527-2&_r=1&z=1225118375


www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 _j1              (&jid) 43634674
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 adSenseId        (&a)   951092047
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 apiVersion       (&v)   1
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 clientId         (&cid) 96833174.1417007305
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 encoding         (&de)  UTF-8
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 flashVersion     (&fl)  15.0 r0
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 hitType          (&t)   pageview
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 javaEnabled      (&je)  1
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 language         (&ul)  nl
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 location         (&dl)  http://www.benelux-pet.com/BE/NL/index.html
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 screenResolution (&sr)  1440x900
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 title            (&dt)  Benelux
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 trackingId       (&tid) UA-49537527-2
www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js:10 viewportSize     (&vp)  1425x805
```

Comment: What is your site, is it benelux-pet.com? If it is, then there doesn't appear to any analytics on the site at all.

Comment: @nyuen, the site is at http://www.benelux-pet.com/BE/NL/index.html

Comment: Code looks alright. Did you check the "Pageviews (last 30minutes)" Tab in RTV ? Since this is basically a single page  you won't get many views in any case, you should implement virtual pageviews for that scrolly thing.

Comment: give it time it takes 48 hours before it will pick up a new tracker.  It doesnt go an check your site instantly

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers, it seems it just needed some time. I checked today and data is flowing in. I had read on other post that if analytics has just been installed it may say "status uninstalled" but you should see, in real time view, your own visit being tracked. that wasn't the case for me... But any way, all is working now!

again, thank you for your responses!